# PHP, Clear the contents of a tag randomly

Tags: php

I'm currently pulling a RSS feed from BBC News which displays multiple items each with these tags:

```
 <summary><?php echo($item->description); ?></summary>
 <media:comment>Automatic=No</media:comment>
```

I'm trying to have some items having empty summarys and some having their content pulled from the feed as normal i.e not empty.

If the summary is empty "Automatic=No" but if it has content "Automatic=Yes".

Please can someone help me figure out how to create the random summary content and "if" condition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can use [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Ex:

```
// Generate a random integer 0 or 1
if(rand()&1 == 1)
{
    echo "<media:comment>Automatic=No</media:comment>";
}
else
{
    echo "<media:comment>Automatic=Yes</media:comment>";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be rand(0, 1); php.net/rand

Comment: It's the same, but it's faster to use bitwise operations when you need a random number that's less than some power of two.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this in replacement of:
      <media:comment>Automatic=No</media:comment>
But it hasn't worked for some reason